# Guava Maps.uniqueIndex doesn't allow duplicates

Tags: guava

When I use Maps.uniqueIndex with a List that contains a duplicate value,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: 836
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
```

is thrown.

I find this inconvenient. I suppose it does make some sense, but if a unique collection is required for the function to work correctly, why does it accept an Iterable as an argument in stead of a Set?

```
List<GroupVO> groups = groupDao.getAll(groupIds);

Map<String,GroupVO> groupMap groupMap = Maps.uniqueIndex(groups, new Function<GroupVO,String>() {
    public String apply(GroupVO vo) {
        return vo.getId().toString();
}});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is simply not possible to have multiple values for one key in a plain `Map`, thus `uniqueIndex` cannot do anything else.

It accepts `Iterable` because accepting only `Set` would restrict its possible usages and still not solve the problem. Not the values in the given `Iterable` need to be unique, but the result of applying the given function on each of them.

If you need multiple values per key, you can simply use [`Multimaps.index`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-), which does the same but returns a `Multimap` (which can contain an arbitrary number of values per key).

Comment: I wish there was a version of this function that would just quietly overwrites in stead of throwing an exception. Just got bitten again with an unexpected condition occurring. It seems that the checking necessary to make sure that this function doesn't accidently fail, more than eliminates  its advantages (in my case)

Answer (score 5):

I think what confuses people here (including me when I'm not paying attention) is that typical Maps (e.g. HashMap) will quietly accept writing a new value to a key; the new value replaces the old one, so if the values are also the same, it's a silent no-op. The Immutable*.Builder family throws under the same circumstances.